# Azure billing information with powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

Is there any way to get the billing information (time and money spent) for a specific resource group by using powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Get-UsageAggregates` [cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619285.aspx) of Microsoft Azure Powershell to get billing information.

See this blog post for an example of how to use this Cmdlet: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2015/06/30/export-azure-subscription-usage-with-new-billing-api-and-powershell.aspx.

First use `Login-AzureRmAccount` cmdlet and then use below command to get the data.

`Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime "2016-01-01" -ReportedEndTime "2016-01-07" -AggregationGranularity "Daily" -ShowDetails $true`

[image]

Using above information and data which you can get from `RateCard API` you can get the cost occurred as well.

Comment: Turned out I was not the service admin or co-admin for the subscription, so therefore I was not authorized to retrive the information..